# In Perforce, is there a way to mark that a file should never be integrated?

Tags: perforce

In our Perforce workspaces at work, there are a couple of control files that contain branch information that should never be integrated across branches.

Is there a way to tell Perforce to always ignore these files in integrations?

Answer (score 6):

You could set up a branch spec and use that for your integrations.

Comment: We have scripts that will set up the branch spec and correctly modify the files so there is never a "bad" version checked in. The issue is handling coworkers who manually branch without using the script.

Comment: My personal preference for handling coworkers who break process is car bombs.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use some type of permissions through `p4 protect`, so that only the admin can modify them.  I know this works for actually checking out and checking in a file, but I'm not sure about integrating it to another branch.

Comment: 5000+ person company. Getting any kind of "p4 admin" access involves black magic.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a server-side trigger script that looks for the control file names and filters them out of an integrate.

There's pretty good [documentation](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4sag/06_scripting.html) on triggers. There's a load of examples too in the public Perforce depot.